# Fortran Compiling Error (Preconditioned Conjugate gradient method) : I tried to compile fortran code and got errors

Tags: loops, compiler-errors, fortran

I tried to compile following code and got following Errors, Guys can
you help me to solve this Errors

**Code:**

```
    DIMENSION x(*),b(*),g(*),h(*),cg(*)
    DIMENSION aa(*),ja(*),ia(*),al(*)
C    
    DO 1 K=1, kMax
C    
        IF (k.EQ.1) THEN
            CALL IAmul(n,aa,ia,ja,x,h)
            DO 2 i=1,n 
                cg(i)=b(i)-h(i)
                g(i)=cg(i)
2           CONTINUE
            CAll ISolvSys(n,g,al,ia,ja)
            gcg=0.
            DO 3 i=1,n 
                gcg=gcg+g(i)*cg(i)
                h(i)=g(i)
3           CONTINUE
        ENDIF
C    
        CALL IAmul (n,aa,ia,ja,h,b)
        hAh=0.
        DO 10 i=1,n 
            hAh=hAh+h(i)*b(i)
10      CONTINUE
        ro=gcg/hAh
        DO 11 i=1,n 
            cg(i)=cg(i)-r0*h(i)
11      CONTINUE
        CALL ISolvSys(n,al,iaja)
        DO 12 i=1,n 
            x(i)=x(i)+ro*h(i)
            g(i)=g(i)-ro*b(i)
12      CONTINUE
        gamma=gcg
        gcg=0 
        DO 13 i=1,n 
            gcg=gcg+g(i)*cg(i)
13      CONTINUE
C 
C 
        write(*,*)'iteration:',k, 'gcg=',gcg
        IF(k.EQ.1) eps=eps*gcg
        IF (gcg.LT.eps) RETURN
        gamma=gcg/gamma 
        DO 14 i=1,n 
            h(i)=g(i)+gamma*h(i)
14      CONTINUE
C 
C
1   CONTINUE
    END
```

**Errors:**

```
      6 |         DO i=1,n
          |                 2
    ......
       12 |         DO i=1,n
          |                 1
    Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
    <span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',16)">main.f95:16:7</span>:
       16 |     ENDIF
          |       1
    Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1)
    <span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',20)">main.f95:20:13</span>:
       12 |         DO i=1,n
          |                 2
    ......
       20 |     DO i=1,n
          |             1
    Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
    <span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',24)">main.f95:24:13</span>:
       20 |     DO i=1,n
          |             2
    ......
       24 |     DO i=1,n
          |             1
    Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
    <span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',28)">main.f95:28:13</span>:
       24 |     DO i=1,n
          |             2
    ......
       28 |     DO i=1,n
          |             1
    Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
    <span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',34)">main.f95:34:13</span>:
       28 |     DO i=1,n
          |             2
    ......
       34 |     DO i=1,n
          |             1
    Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
    <span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',41)">main.f95:41:13</span>:
       34 |     DO i=1,n
          |             2
    ......
       41 |     DO i=1,n
          |             1
    Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
    <span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',45)">main.f95:45:3</span>:
       45 | END
          |   1
    Error: END DO statement expected at (1)
    f951: Error: Unexpected end of file in ‘main.f95’





   

 6 |         DO i=1,n
      |                 2
......

   12 |         DO i=1,n
      |                 1
Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',16)">main.f95:16:7</span>:
   16 |     ENDIF
      |       1
Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1)
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',20)">main.f95:20:13</span>:
   12 |         DO i=1,n
      |                 2
......
   20 |     DO i=1,n
      |             1
Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',24)">main.f95:24:13</span>:
   20 |     DO i=1,n
      |             2
......
   24 |     DO i=1,n
      |             1
Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',28)">main.f95:28:13</span>:
   24 |     DO i=1,n
      |             2
......
   28 |     DO i=1,n
      |             1
Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',34)">main.f95:34:13</span>:
   28 |     DO i=1,n
      |             2
......
   34 |     DO i=1,n
      |             1
Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',41)">main.f95:41:13</span>:
   34 |     DO i=1,n
      |             2
......
   41 |     DO i=1,n
      |             1
Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.f95',45)">main.f95:45:3</span>:
   45 | END
      |   1
Error: END DO statement expected at (1)
f951: Error: Unexpected end of file in ‘main.f95’
```

If a Fortran expert could clarify that issue I would be most grateful.

Comment: It's hard to see how the error messages you give relate to the code. Either way, we need to see more detail rather than simply part of a procedure. See [mre].

Comment: I have to agree with @francescalus - given in your code example I can't see a single line that reads `DO i=1,n` I can't see how your error messages relate to what you have presented.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `DO` loops are not being properly terminated. Each of your `DO` loops continues the previous one, hence the compiler says:

```
Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/fortran_do_loop.htm

A bigger problem is that you are using a Fortran 95 compiler, and yet the code is not Fortran 95. I'd guess that the code is Fortran 77. Please check your compiler manual and try to select Fortran 77.

https://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/09_loops.html

Comment: Which features of the code fragment show are not Fortran 95?  Which DO construct shown is not terminated? (I haven't asked a compiler, but I can't see a single one that isn't terminated correctly, so showing the error(s) and corrections would be helpful.)

Comment: Fortran95 is close to a strict superset of Fortran77. Fortran is amazingly backward compatible. Using a modern compiler on what has been shown shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The fixed format is broken. When I copy the code and compile it, there are four columns before the code - there should be six. I have corrected my copy. Now it complains about DIMENSION, Assumed size array at (1) must be a dummy argument (GFortran).

Comment: @FrancisKing I don't think your answer is right. All of the `do` loops in the OP's code fragment appear to be correctly terminated, using the old `do label; label continue` style. See e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn83/index.html) for this.

Comment: @veryreverie: The original poster has given us main.95 code. So, we are looking at a Fortran 95 file. Except we're not, we've got fixed format Fortran 77. I posted two webpages showing the correct way to do loops in the two languages. When I compiled as a .f file, leaving the compiler to decide what to do a) the fixed format is wrong (too few columns) and it doesn't like the DIMENSION statement. The errors shown seem to correspond to problems with terminating the loops, so that a new loop starts before the old one is finished - different to the shown code. I am confused.

Comment: I agree the OP's code is neither valid fixed-form nor free-form Fortran. (although note that this has nothing to do with Fortran 77 vs Fortran 95). Also, the OP's error message does not match their code. But I still disagree with your statement "Each of your `DO` loops continues the previous one". The `do label; label continue` syntax is perfectly valid in free-form fortran and in all modern fortran standards (albeit bad practice in modern code).

Comment: Also, your statement "the code is not Fortran 95. I'd guess that the code is Fortran 77". As Ian Bush has said above, if the code is valid Fortran 77 (which it is not), then it is also valid Fortran 95 (except possibly for some very niche edge cases which I am unaware of).